# How to parse data between <td colspan="2"> and </td>

Tags: javascript, html, beautifulsoup

I want to parse the information between `<td colspan="2">...</td>` under `<th>Number of samples</th>`.For example, after parsing the following html will return 64.

```
...
<tr class="border"> 
    <th>Average FPKM</th>
    <td colspan="2">0.8</td>
</tr>
<tr class="border">
    <th>Number of samples</th>
    <td colspan="2">64</td>
</tr>   
...
```

How to get only return the value 64 here?

Thanks

Comment: Hello, I suppose he wants to get this value with beautifulsoup, a python library. Here is the documentation for beautiful soup: https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/

Comment: Please, post the code in details i.e. with div and table, so that we can use javascript on it.

Comment: Please post your own solution and mark it as an answer so that this can be useful to others.

Comment: Please note that all answers return 64 as string and not as integer. Use the `parseInt` function to convert from string to integer.

Comment: I just use 'Number = soup.find('th',text = "Number of samples").find_next_sibling("td").text' to find out the string 64 and then convert to int later

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First give the table cell an id, for this example I chose `tableCell`

Using pure JavaScript and no jQuery, this code does exactly what you want

```
var value = document.getElementById("tableCell").innerHTML
```

Using jQuery you can do this:

```
var value = $("#tableCell").html()
```

Comment: Great! Would be nice if you could mark my post as the answer

Answer (score 1):

Get th, then parent, then find td.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var thGet=$('table').find('th');
  $.each(thGet, function (i, obj) {
    var text = $(obj).text();
    if(text == 'Number of samples' && $(obj).parent().find('td').attr('colspan') == '2')
    {
        alert($(obj).parent().find('td').html());
    }
  });
});
```

non jQuery, need Javascript support

```
var x = document.querySelectorAll('th');
for (var i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    if(x[i].innerHTML == 'Number of samples')
    {
        var c = x[i].parentNode.childNodes;
      var j;
      for (j = 0; j < c.length; j++) {
          if(c[j].tagName == 'TD' && c[j].colSpan == '2')
          {
            console.log(c[j].innerHTML);
          }
      }
    }
};
```

Comment: Note: This solution requires jQuery

Answer (score 1):

You can follow this approach with pure Javascript.I assumed the structure of table `tr` doesn't change.

1. Select all `tr.border`
2. Iterate them and find which one has `Number of samples` very simply. Then get what you want.

```js
window.onload = () => {
    let tr = document.querySelectorAll('tr.border')
    tr.forEach((elm) => {
        if(elm.innerText.indexOf('Number of samples') == 0)
            console.log(elm.querySelector('td').innerText)
    })
};
```

```html
<table>
<tr class="border"> 
    <th>Average FPKM</th>
    <td colspan="2">0.8</td>
</tr>
<tr class="border">
    <th>Number of samples</th>
    <td colspan="2">64</td>
</tr>   
</table>
```

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you need the last cell of the last row of a table and that you are using jQuery.

```
let result = $('table tr:last-child td:last-child').text();
```

[Here is example](https://codepen.io/adityasharat/pen/VrNRxX)